# OpenCV: findContours seems to be tricked by combination of large filled areas and lines

Tags: opencv, image-segmentation

I want to process the output from external image segmentation algorithm (the left frame), which consists of the large color-filled areas and contour lines between them. The grayscale image that is used to find contours seems Ok (right frame), so I don't think that `Canny` thresholds are the issue. However, when I try to find contours on this image (frame in the middle) I get this result. How can I detect the big areas properly?

[image: example]

```
  int thresh = 100;

  // segmenting received image by external algorithm
  Felzenszwalb_segment(seg,src2_bgr,k,0.5,500); 

  // finding contours on the segmented image

  Mat src_gray;

  cvtColor( src2_bgr, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );

  imshow("gray", src_gray);


  Mat canny_output;
  vector<vector<Point> > contours;
  vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;  

  /// Detect edges using canny
  Canny( src_gray, canny_output, thresh, thresh*2, 3 );
  /// Find contours      
  findContours( canny_output, 
        contours, 
        hierarchy, 
        CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```

If it's needed, here is [the segmentation algorithm](http://de.inf.ua/misc/Felzenszwalb_segment.zip) I'm using, the file to include is `segment.cpp`, usage is shown in the commented out `main()` function.

Comment: Your segmentation algorithm can't know that the existing contours aren't part of the image. Can you get the first image without the contours?

Comment: @barny I'm trying to find contours on the output of the algorithm (left image, `src2_bgr`). The reason why I mentioned the algorithm was to explain where I get such an image as the input (colored areas with some drawn contour lines). Sorry if that looks unclear

Comment: @barny No, I can't get the image without contour lines, I studied the algorithm but I can't see where they actually appear. It seems that they may not even be contour lines but some weird contour as well

Comment: can't you  just mask your image for each color separately and then find contours for each mask?!?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to get one contour for each colored field, or one single contour for the whole body?

Comment: @Micka Yes, that's how I finally approached this problem. I found all unique colors on the segmentation output image and then used `cv::inRange` to extract corresponding segments separately. I need each contour separately as a mask because my idea is to compare them with backprojection results via `bitwise_and` to find skin regions with good accuracy. Thank you!

Comment: cool idea, good luck and thx for the segmentaton link